# Determine continuity of two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Examine the following function for continuity

$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{|y|}\sqrt{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $y\neq0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $y=0$}
\end{cases}$

i think function is not continuous for any point  $(x,0),x\neq0$ .  this  point  can  be approach through vertical line passing through  in upper half plane that point giving me limit $|x |$, which is not equal function value. At any other point function is continuous.
right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $x_n = (x_0,1/n)$ and $y_n=(x_0, -1/n)$. Then $f(x_n) = \sqrt{x_0^2 + 1/n^2} \longrightarrow |x_0|$ while $f(y_n) = -\sqrt{x_0^2 + 1/n^2} \longrightarrow - |x_0|$. Therefore if $x_0 \neq 0$, $f$ is not continuous at $(x_0,0)$. It's left to check what happens when $x_0=0$, though it's quite clear that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$